# Cache issue in angular 7 while updating changes on server

Tags: angular, angular7, browser-cache

I have a angular application, its working fine. The problem i am facing is below -:
1) Each time while i am doing any changes and uploading those on server, those changes does not reflect till i don't hard refresh the browser.
2) I tried to find out solution for this and only solution found in most of the thread is -:
   a) Building application with [ng build --prod --output-hashing=all]
3) Still i am getting same issue,changes not getting reflected till hard refresh, **is there any way to resolve this problem in angular 7?**

Comment: Can you share your content of angular.json ?

Comment: @Yogendra123, it something like this -:"outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts","optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,

Comment: Its not clear, please share entire file or git repo and what are the name of chunks created when you do a build ?

Answer (score 0):

can you check whether browser not caching your web service response.

```
 httpHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
   'Expires': 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT'
});

 return this.httpClient.get<Test[]>(this.resourcePrefix+'/getData',{ headers: 
 this.httpHeader})
```

This type of caching issue i was also facing in IE when using datatable as browser was caching response received and after refresh show latest data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing to remove caching issue in angular projects.Add versioning to your project. To add versioning from scratch follow this link..

> https://medium.com/@jpatwa/angular-versioning-and-production-build-caching-issue-4398ed432f46